# How to import other js file without installing runtime

Tags: javascript

I want to use a class declare in a JS file without installing runtime(hopefully pure JS or like pure).

it looks there is a way installing runtime and "import xxx from filename.js". but I don't have permission to install on server. also I tried babel-standalone to use require().

tried babel-standalone to use require()

Both are same directly

app.js

message.js

**app.js**

```
mes = require("message.js");

mes.notice();
```

**message.js**

```
class message {

    constructor(subject, text) {

        this.subject = "subject";

        this.text = "text";

    }    

    notice() {

        alert(this.subject + '\n' + this.text);

    }

}

const mes = new message();

module.exports = mes;
```

I expect alert 
"subject
 text".
But no respond. and it says "require is not defined" and I found it doesn't work on client side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have done

```
const mes = new message();
```

However, your message class has a constructor that takes in the parameters subject and text. Did you mean to do

```
const mes = new message("A subject", "A text");
```

In client side javascript you can't use "require". Instead, you can just do something like this (html).

```
<script>
    class message {

        constructor(subject, text) {

            this.subject = "subject";

            this.text = "text";

        }

        notice() {

            alert(this.subject + '\n' + this.text);

        }
    }

    const mes = new message();
</script>
<script>
    mes.notice();
</script>
```

There is no need to use require. Even though there are two different script tags, you can still access the global variables.

**Update:**
What you could do is have another script tag

```
<script src="message.js">
    var notice = function(mes){
        mes.notic();
    }
</script>

Then whenever you need to 'notice' a message from the other script (app.js), you can just call notice(message);
```

Comment: thanks for telling me I can't use "require". 
const mes = new message(); is just 
for "mes.notice();" when do it one file.

I load "app.js" in index.html with
<script type="text/babel" type="module" src="app.js"></script>

is there any way to load other JS file from "app.js"?

Comment: I don't think you can lead another script using app.js. One way that you can do it is have another script tag with src="message.js". Then  in message.js you can have a message function which you can call in app.js. See updated answer.

Comment: I noticed that we don't need declare var. we can call "mes" from app.js as long as load message.js first.